# How to import folders to Android studio

Tags: android-studio, directory

Am new to Android studio.. But wanted to start a new project but don't know how to import all my project folders to Android studio..the folders and file that I want to import is shown in the screenshot below..any assistance will be appreciate.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZZ7R.png)

Comment: This is not really the place for learning how to set up an Android Studio project. So many better places for that.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: A Google search? A book? A colleague? Copying a Github project you like and seeing what they do?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions..